# Why does for loop using i++ appear to increment by 2 instead of 1?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a logic question about the mechanics of `for` loops.

In the following simple loop I anticipated that the first 3 DIV elements would have their classes changed from box_1 to box_2.  However instead of box 1, 2 and 3 turning blue box 1, 3 and 5 turned blue.  Why does it appear that the loop is incrementing by 2 instead of 1? I'm sure that I"m missing something.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".box_1")[i].className = "box_2";
}
```

```css
.box_1 {
 padding: 8px;
 margin: 0 0 16px 0;
 font-size: 2rem;
 color: white;
 background-color: red;
}

.box_2 {
 padding: 8px;
 margin: 0 0 16px 0;
 font-size: 2rem;
 color: white;
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box_1">1</div>
<div class="box_1">2</div>
<div class="box_1">3</div>
<div class="box_1">4</div>
<div class="box_1">5</div>
<div class="box_1">6</div>
<div class="box_1">7</div>
<div class="box_1">8</div>
<div class="box_1">9</div>
<div class="box_1">10</div>
```

Comment: Just a little tip, you can actually do this with a CSS selector.. eg.. `for (let el of document.querySelectorAll(".box_1:nth-child(-n+3)")) el.className = "box_2";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

document.querySelectorAll(".box_1") is getting called each loop. Causing the odd results. If you store the initial query. Then the results are expected.

```js
let nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".box_1");
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  nodeList[i].className = "box_2";
}
```

```css
.box_1 {
 padding: 8px;
 margin: 0 0 16px 0;
 font-size: 2rem;
 color: white;
 background-color: red;
}

.box_2 {
 padding: 8px;
 margin: 0 0 16px 0;
 font-size: 2rem;
 color: white;
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box_1">1</div>
<div class="box_1">2</div>
<div class="box_1">3</div>
<div class="box_1">4</div>
<div class="box_1">5</div>
<div class="box_1">6</div>
<div class="box_1">7</div>
<div class="box_1">8</div>
<div class="box_1">9</div>
<div class="box_1">10</div>
```

Good article about a NodeList vs HTMLCollection https://hackernoon.com/htmlcollection-nodelist-and-array-of-objects-da42737181f9

Comment: Thanks so much you are 100% correct! I have one small question.  When I use your code but change it to `nodeList = document.getElementsByClassName("box_1");` it breaks in the exact same way again.  Why does `querySelectorAll` work but  `getElementsByClassName` break?  That I'm puzzled on.

Comment: @DR01D, correct! querySelectorAll returns a non-live NodeList. getElementsByClassName returns a live HTMLCollection.

Answer (score 4):

Every time the loop runs, the 0th element of `box_1` is now the *next* item, since the previous 0th element is no longer in that class.  In other words, the second time through the loop is this

```
<div class="box_2">1</div>
<div class="box_1">2</div> <-- This is now the [0] element
<div class="box_1">3</div> <-- This is now the [1] element
<div class="box_1">4</div>
<div class="box_1">5</div>
<div class="box_1">6</div>
<div class="box_1">7</div>
<div class="box_1">8</div>
<div class="box_1">9</div>
<div class="box_1">10</div>
```